# Is it possible to undo an apt-get install command?

Tags: apt, uninstall

I installed Carpadio on my Xubuntu install (a Live USB), which then pulled like over 50 packages from, I suppose, the Ubuntu side of the repository. Now I would like to undo this. However for all my hunting, I can't find anything more useful than [How can I reverse sudo apt get install command](https://superuser.com/questions/143629/how-can-i-reverse-sudo-apt-get-install-command), which just suggests `apt-get purge`. This is not useful since all it does is remove 2 packages (carpadio and carpadio-gnomepanel).

`/var/log/apt/history.log` has a list of all the packages that was installed along with that command. **So I was wondering if there is any easy way to go about removing all of them**? Else I can just reinstall, this was a fresh install anyway, but I am curious.

A small sample of the history log (1/5-1/10 of the entire list)

> Commandline: apt-get install cardapio-gnomepanel
>   Install: libdbusmenu-qt2:amd64 (0.9.2-0ubuntu1, automatic), python-packagekit:amd64 (0.7.2-4ubuntu3, automatic), cups-pk-helper:amd64 (0.2.1.2-1ubuntu0.1, automatic), geoclue:amd64 (0.12.0-1ubuntu12, automatic), unity:amd64 (5.18.0-0ubuntu1, automatic), indicator-printers:amd64 (0.1.6-0ubuntu1, automatic), libevolution:amd64 (3.2.3-0ubuntu6, automatic), libqt4-declarative:amd64 (4.8.1-0ubuntu4.3, automatic), libmtp9:amd64 (1.1.3-1ubuntu0.1, automatic), tracker-miner-fs:amd64 (0.14.0-2ubuntu1, automatic), gir1.2-rb-3.0:amd64 (2.96-0ubuntu4.2, automatic), python-aptdaemon.pkcompat:amd64 (0.43+bzr805-0ubuntu7, automatic), gnome-media:amd64 (3.4.0-0ubuntu3.1, automatic), metacity:amd64 (2.34.1-1ubuntu11, automatic), nautilus:amd64 (3.4.2-0ubuntu6, automatic), libcompizconfig0:amd64 (0.9.7.0~bzr428-0ubuntu6, automatic), compiz-plugins-default:amd64 (0.9.7.12-0ubuntu1, automatic), libunistring0:amd64 (0.9.3-5, automatic), libebackend-1.2-1:amd64 (3.2.3-0ubuntu7, automatic), ubuntu-docs:amd64 (12.04.6, automatic), python-mako:amd64 (0.5.0-1, automatic),

To all those who have suggested `autoremove`: I am not sure why, but I got just 1 other python related package (python-keybinder or something) as "unnecessary" and that is all that autoremove was able to remove.

Between the install and uninstall, only major change was installing `xubuntu-restricted-extras`.

Comment: It's a bit late to be of help in this case, but the next time you want to install something, consider doing a simulation first. Run `sudo apt-get install -s package` where `-s` denotes a simulation and `package` will be replaced by the appropriate software's name.

Comment: @vasa1 Yes, am beating my self up about this. apt-get asks [Y/n] as well, that should have been my out..

Comment: *I got just 1 other python related package (python-keybinder or summat) as "unnecessary"* Did you actually remove the `cardapio-gnomepanel` package?

Comment: @gertvdijk yes, `apt-get remove carpadio` took that one along too.

Comment: @KarthikT Then I'm completely lost as to why `autoremove` isn't working for you. Either you somehow marked all packages as manually installed now or there's a plain misunderstanding. It's very simple: `apt-get autoremove` just removes all automatically installed marked packages without a reason to have them now. If it doesn't work for you, I think you have changed something on your system you didn't tell about in your question.

Comment: All I did after installing carpadio and before removing it, was installing xubuntu-restricted-extras. I didnt expect that to have unity, etc as dependants, thus I didnt mention it.

Comment: @gertvdijk and the "system" is a persistant live usb, I dunno if that makes a difference.

Comment: @KarthikT Nope, both are unrelated to my knowledge, but good to include that in your question anyway.

Comment: [My question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/176228/how-to-use-sed-to-edit-var-log-apt-history-log-in-order-to-apt-get-remove-numer) handled virtually an identical problem.  The key to solving it was running a one liner on the relevant portion of the apt log and pasting the output after a familiar `sudo apt-get remove`

Comment: Fedora shines here: `dnf history --reverse`, `dnf history rollback <number>`.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Basically, you'll have to both `apt-get remove` (or apt-get purge) the package **and** run `apt-get autoremove` after that, to have it revert the installation of `package-one`.

Let's look at the whole process:

- `sudo apt-get install package-one` *installs 50 dependencies with it marked "automatic" as also can be seen from the log excerpt in your question*
- `sudo apt-get purge package-one` *removes (purges) just one, but **do** run this!*

  All following install actions (if you run any) will yield an informational message with the no longer needed packages:

  ```
  The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
    package-two package-three [...]
  Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
  ```

  This list is basically just a list of all packages marked as "automatic" without a reverse dependency on them. In other words, there's no reason for them to be installed as far as the package management is concerned.

  *Note: No installation is needed! It's just to demonstrate that APT is smart to tell you about your unneeded packages!*
- `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge` *removes (purges) these*

#### More information

- Official documentation on `autoremove` from the `apt-get(8)` manpage:

  > `autoremove` is used to remove packages that were automatically installed to satisfy dependencies for other packages and are now no longer needed.
- [What is the correct way to completely remove an application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187888/what-is-the-correct-way-to-completely-remove-an-application)

Comment: In this OP has pulled in Unity and all its friends. I doubt purging cardapio will remove Unity etc even after autoremove.

Comment: @vasa1 Why? The packages are marked as 'automatically installed' (as can be seen in the question) and if no reason can be found for those to be installed on the system, they will be suggested for removal using `autoremove`.

Comment: Yes, I was wondering about the "automatic". If that serves to indicate autoremoval that's good. OP should have no problems then.

Comment: @gertvdijk good catch by @vasa1, pls see my edit. `autoremove` did not help.

Comment: @gertvdijk, for "Subsequent install actions", would a `sudo apt-get update` be sufficient?

Comment: @gertvdijk, so autoremove is only triggered when there is something to install (or upgrade)? Because I get the autoremove prompt even after `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`. Of course, install and upgrade maybe seen as the same thing.

Comment: @gertvdijk, So OP should actually install some small program in order to get an effective "autoremove"?

Comment: @gertvdijk, this confused me: "Subsequent install actions". Now it's gone.

Comment: @vasa1 subsequent actions were not needed. The act of remove itself prompted me with the message that the 1 package was unwanted.

Comment: @KarthikT But that information is regarding the state *before* removing `package-one`. So, this information is not about the state you're about to put the system in.

Comment: @gertvdijk I am marking this as the answer for being the best written answer of the official method. I think I will just reinstall though. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @KarthikT Feel free to unaccept it any time if you find a solution to the issue that does work in your case.

Comment: Suppose you wanted to undo an update. Could you replace "package-one" with "update" ? Thanks.

Answer (score 22):

When you want to remove a package and its dependencies that installed at the time, you should use:

```
sudo apt-get purge package
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove
```

but to undo `apt` actions, you can use `apt-undo` script. It is a simple script that can undo the `apt` actions performed in Ubuntu. It is to be noted that this script can only work if you use it instead of `apt-get` to install/upgrade/remove/purge/downgrade your packages.

To install `apt-undo` in Ubuntu, run the following commands in the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lkjoel/apt-undo
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apt-undo
```

usage:

```
apt-undo install yourpackages
apt-undo remove yourpackages
apt-undo purge yourpackages
apt-undo upgrade
apt-undo dist-upgrade
apt-undo install yourpackages=old.version
apt-undo install yourpackages=new.version
```

To undo, the above `aptitude` actions run following commands in the terminal:

```
apt-undo undo
```

Comment: Thanks, I came across this, and it sounded like exactly what the doctor ordered, until I saw the caveat that I needed to use it to install, to be able to undo..

Comment: Nice catch. Very confusing syntax, though. And I really don't like to use alternatives to well-tested core APT application. Still +1!

Answer (score 7):

Use the power of Unix. Take the log file line that you have, and construct a command that will undo what apt did. For example:

```
$ echo 'Install: libdbusmenu-qt2:amd64 (0.9.2-0ubuntu1, automatic), python-packagekit:amd64 (0.7.2-4ubuntu3, automatic), cups-pk-helper:amd64 (0.2.1.2-1ubuntu0.1, automatic),'|perl -pe 's/ \(.*?\)//g; s/,//g; s/^Install: //'
libdbusmenu-qt2:amd64 python-packagekit:amd64 cups-pk-helper:amd64
```

So you can use this purge all packages you installed accidentally, given the appropriate line from your log file:

```
$ dpkg -P $(echo '(full log line here)' | perl -pe 's/ \(.*?\)//g; s/,//g; s/^Install: //')
```

(I've used `perl` instead of `sed` because `sed` uses a type of regular expression which doesn't support non-greedy matches, which was the easiest way of constructing what I needed)

Comment: Nice script, but it should really be just sequence of commands people can remember to accomplish it.

Comment: Thanks, intimidating script, but I was afraid it would come down to this

Comment: I used very similar code to solve my [very similar problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/176228/how-to-use-sed-to-edit-var-log-apt-history-log-in-order-to-apt-get-remove-numer).  I did it in several steps just to be more sure about what was happening.  First I copied relevant block of text from the `apt` log into a new file and then applied this to it: `perl -pe 's/\(.*?\)(, )?//g' /path/to/apt-history.log`  Then all I did was prepend that output with `sudo apt-get remove` and I was good to go!

Answer (score 4):

To undo the last apt install you may also use this:

```
sudo apt purge $(grep "Install:" /var/log/apt/history.log | tail -n 1 | tr " " "\n" | grep -E ":amd64|:i386|:arm" | tr "\n" " ")
```

This will catch the last apt install from the history and suggests to purge the corresponding packages. apt will display you a list of all packages in question which needs to be confirmed, so you keep control about what happens.

You can create a function called ”aptpurgelastinstall“ by executing this command:

```
echo -e "\n# undo the last apt installation with aptpurgelastinstall" >> ~/.bashrc && echo 'aptpurgelastinstall () { sudo apt purge $(grep "Install:" /var/log/apt/history.log | tail -n 1 | tr " " "\n" | grep -E ":amd64|:i386|:arm" | tr "\n" " ") ; }' >> ~/.bashrc && . ~/.bashrc
```

Now you simply need to type **aptpurgelastinstall** in a shell to undo the last installation.

---

If you want to specify how many previous installations should be purged (all in one step), then change the 1 in the code to $1.

Then you can type for instance **aptpurgelastinstall 3** in the shell and the last three installations will be completely purged.

Answer (score 2):

1. Paste the long list of unwanted packages from the apt log (var/log/apt/history.log) into a `new_file.txt`
2. Execute `perl -pe 's/\(.*?\)(, )?//g' /path/to/new_file.txt`
3. Copy the output of the last command to the clipboard or [pipe it there in the first place](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184397/how-do-i-pipe-terminal-standard-output-stdout-to-the-clipboard).
4. Execute `sudo apt-get remove` [paste the contents of the clipboard here]

Done.

Basically we need to format the list of packages from the apt log into something apt-get can understand.  The parenthesis, words in between, and the commas need to go so that's where the perl comes in to play.  Yes, there are better (more efficient) ways - but I've done this, its easy to understand, and it works.

Comment: +1 for personal experience and explanation, but as I have mentioned earlier, I have already reset my Live USB

Answer (score 1):

After you remove the one package, and you can remove it thoroughly by adding --purge, for, `apt-get remove --purge <package>`, it should give you a message that the library packages it pulled in were installed automatically and no longer necessary, at which point you can run `apt-get autoremove` to remove them.

Comment: Thanks, but autoremove proved to be insufficient in this case. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the `sudo apt-get purge packagename` with

```
sudo apt-get autoremove.
```

Unless it's metapackage this should take care of it.

Also see the faq at [How do I manually remove *all* Cardapio files?](https://answers.launchpad.net/cardapio/+faq/1185).

Comment: Thanks, but autoremove proved to be insufficient in this case. Please see my edit. Thank you for the FAQ link, very useful!

Comment: Some of those packages may be needed by other things and not marked as able to be autoremoved. Did you look at the instructions at the link? How are those?

Comment: The instructions on the link are rather orthogonal to the core issue, and as it is, I am leaning towards reinstalling my system. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Technically "remove" or "autoremove" operations are not "undo" although they can be made to do the job good enough most of the times.

By default, apt-get will leave packages behind, unless you specify `-o APT::Suggests-Important=0 -o APT::Recommends-Important=0`

It is more reliable to take a look at the apt `history.log` and uninstall all the installed packages. I have created a small node-based script to ease the process:

https://github.com/rolfen/apt-history

Also, here is another, more manual approach to "rolling back" changes:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/236711

Answer (score 1):

To undo the action of the `sudo apt install` command, you want to do two things:

1. Uninstall the packages that command installed
2. Undo the marking of the packages that were marked as "manually installed" and marked them as "automatically installed" instead

For example, let's say I installed a bunch of build dependencies for something:

```
$ sudo apt install build-essential libgl1-mesa-dev libxkbcommon-x11-0 libpulse-dev libgles-dev libgles1 libglvnd-core-dev libglvnd-dev libopengl-dev
```

It's impossible to tell just from the text of this command to know how to undo it, because we don't know yet which packages this command installed, which packages were marked as manually installed, and which packages were unaffected (since they were already installed and marked as manually installed). We need to look at the output of that command first, and for each line, undo it.

Here's the output:

```
$ sudo apt install build-essential libgl1-mesa-dev libxkbcommon-x11-0 libpulse-dev libgles-dev libgles1 libglvnd-core-dev libglvnd-dev libopengl-dev
build-essential is already the newest version (12.9ubuntu2).
libxcb-glx0 is already the newest version (1.14-3ubuntu1).
libxcb-glx0 set to manually installed.
The following NEW packages will be installed
  libgl1-mesa-dev libgles-dev libgles1 libglvnd-core-dev libglvnd-dev libopengl-dev libpulse-dev
# output cut for brevity
```

Lines that look line this:

```
libxcb-glx0 is already the newest version (1.14-3ubuntu1).
libxcb-glx0 set to manually installed.
```

... can be undone by running:

```
$ sudo apt-mark auto libxcb-glx0
```

Lines that look like this:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed
  libgl1-mesa-dev libgles-dev libgles1 libglvnd-core-dev libglvnd-dev libopengl-dev libpulse-dev
```

... can be undone by running:

```
$ sudo apt remove libgl1-mesa-dev libgles-dev libgles1 libglvnd-core-dev libglvnd-dev libopengl-dev libpulse-dev
```

Lines that look like this:

```
build-essential is already the newest version (12.9ubuntu2).
```

... do not need to be undone, since the package was already installed and marked as manually installed.

If you just take the list of packages from `sudo apt install` and run `sudo apt remove`, you risk removing packages that depend on these packages, even though those packages were already installed before the `sudo apt install` command was run.

Answer (score 0):

If you have just added a ppa and want to revert, you need to do the steps described below. Understand this can fail, when you've installed other packages you don't want to uninstall. I'm sure this can be done with a script. Personally I think this should be a part of apt, and there should be better administration of which packages are installed because of dependencies and which are installed by request of the user.

1) remove the ppa from /etc/apt/sources.list
Remember the time you added the ppa. If you're lucky, you don't need to be precise.

2) make a list what to reinstall, from the moment you installed the PPA:
cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep 'upgrade '

3) make a list what to remove, from the moment you installed the PPA:
cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep 'install '

4) remove all packages from step 3:
sudo apt-get remove {list of packages from step 3}

5) reinstall all packages from step 2:
sudo apt-get install --reinstall {list of packages from step 2}

6) If things went wrong and you cannot think of a solution, put back the PPA and reinstall all packages from the two lists.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a quite old question but I came here searching for help and maybe I can help someone.
I had a situation similar to @Karthik-T's one after installing `unity8-desktop-session-mir`. I know it's a big one. It pulled 233 packets with him.

Using `autoremove` I get removed only 34 of them.
The point is that during `unity8-desktop-session-mir` installation, it removed two packages (`python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat` and `evolution-data-server-online-accounts`). It's stated in `/var/log/apt/history.log`, after the `Install` section.

To completely undo the Unity 8 installation I issued the followings:

1. `sudo apt-get purge unity8-desktop-session-mir`
2. `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove`
3. `sudo apt-get install python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat evolution-data-server-online-accounts` (it removed 8 packages related to Unity 8)
4. `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove`

This will not remove absolutely everything you installed before, but in some case is good enough.

PS: perhaps the `autoremove` at step two is not necessary, as I issued again at step four.