# How to get rid of unwanted software?

Tags: package-management, uninstall, dependencies, synaptic, muon-package-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the correct way to completely remove an application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187888/what-is-the-correct-way-to-completely-remove-an-application)
>   [Is it possible to undo an apt-get install command?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247549/is-it-possible-to-undo-an-apt-get-install-command)

Most of the time when I want to try a new program, the package manager tells me that I also need to install certain dependencies. Figuring that the program will not work without these dependencies, I install all of them. Sometimes the program is good, other times the program doesn't work or crashes or I just don't like it.

How can I uninstall the program and all the dependencies that were installed with it?

Do I need to manually keep track of what gets installed when and where and what it needs to function?

I don't want a bunch of useless or otherwise unused programs cluttering up my computer, wasting space and slowing my system down. How can I get rid of it without guessing what I should and shouldn't need to keep?

Edited 2/4/2013 to differentiate question:

Is there any way to remove do this without resorting to the command line? I use Muon in kubuntu and Synaptic in lubuntu. Can neither one of these programs remove the software and dependancies that it installs?

Comment: Probable duplicate: [How can I uninstall software?](http://askubuntu.com/q/1143/25656)

Comment: @vasa1 Yes, almost picked that one too, but the accepted answer that Q doesn't mention "autoremove" and automatically installed packages (the other does).

Comment: OP will benefit by reading https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto which has nice summaries of various commands related to installing and removing software.

Comment: @gertvdijk, in totality, that question does answer OP's issues. I'm not sure that mentioning something as a duplicate question requires that the accepted answer, and the accepted answer alone, needs to provide the answer to the current question.

Comment: @vasa1 Agree. I just think the one I marked is a little bit more straightforward to what OP is looking for. Also: [What is the correct way to completely remove an application?](http://askubuntu.com/q/187888/88802)

Comment: I believe your updated question is a bit changed. I would suggest to ask a new question: "How do I perform an 'autoremove' in Muon and Synaptic?" and make it awesome! Please be more specific in your question next time, as you can see users aren't very likely to come up with question you were looking for if you don't mention it all. :)

Answer (score 4):

If you are not a power user or developer who create programs, dependency tracker is there to mark the obsolete package.

Just run

`sudo apt-get autoremove` to remove unused dependency.

Also if you want to clean the downloaded cache files (installers at `/var/cache/apt/archives` that are used for installation you can run

`sudo apt-get clean`